# How to test a Play application using Guice and mocking custom ControllerComponents

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I've started building a new Scala Play! app and I'm wondering how to test a controller that is defined as follows:

```scala
class CustomController @Inject()(
    cc: SecuredControllerComponents,
    clientResourceHandler: CustomResourceHandler
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends SecuredController(cc)
```

I need to mock the `SecuredControllerComponents` that are injected by Guice automatically.

```scala
case class SecuredControllerComponents @Inject()(
    adminActionBuilder: AdminActionBuilder,
    authenticatedActionBuilder: AuthenticatedActionBuilder,
    actionBuilder: DefaultActionBuilder,
    parsers: PlayBodyParsers,
    messagesApi: MessagesApi,
    langs: Langs,
    fileMimeTypes: FileMimeTypes,
    executionContext: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
) extends ControllerComponents

class SecuredController @Inject()(scc: SecuredControllerComponents)
    extends AbstractController(scc) {
  def AdminAction: AdminActionBuilder                       = scc.adminActionBuilder
  def AuthenticatedAction: AuthenticatedActionBuilder       = scc.authenticatedActionBuilder
}
```

The official Play documentation suggests to use `Helpers.stubControllerComponents()` to pass the components to a Controller that has to be tested.

#### Edit - The test that I would like to perform

```scala
    "return a list of Custom Objects as a JSON array" in {
      val controller =
        new CustomController(Helpers.stubControllerComponents(), resourceHandler)
      val result: Future[Result] = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest())
      .....
      val bodyText: String       = contentAsString(result)
      bodyText mustBe "ok"
```

I've gone through [this guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice) about testing with Google Guice but I don't know how to deal with my custom `SecuredComponents` and the `CustomResourceHandler`.

**Could you please point me in the right direction?** Is there any good example to look at?

**My current configuration**

- Scala v2.12.8
- Play 2.7.2
- Scala Guice 4.2.1
- scalatestplus-play 4.0.2

Comment: There are several ways for testing a controller, which one are you trying? posting your failing test would be useful to help you, is not the same if you are testing the methods directly or testing the controller by invoking the routes.

Comment: @AlexITC I added an example of a test that I would like to execute. I need to pass `scc: SecuredControllerComponents` to the CustomController. Do you know a possible workaround. I'm going crazy with this, although it should be the easiest part...

Comment: As @AlexITC pointed out on Gitter this solution could solve the problem entirely: https://github.com/X9Developers/block-explorer/blob/develop/server/test/controllers/BlocksControllerSpec.scala#L31

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is now mocking your classes, for example with *Mockito*:

```
  new CustomController(mySecuredControllerComponentsMock, myCustomResourceHandlerMock)


 ...

 lazy val mySecuredControllerComponentsMock = {
  mock(SecuredControllerComponents.class)
  ...
}
```